# React - Calling an Object Key for Img

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call an image through a dummy dataset in React.

I am using the below:

```
<li>
   <img src={testimonials[0].image} alt={testimonials[0].name}/> 
</li>
```

And my data looks:

```
const testimonials = [
    {
      name: "Julia Cameron",
      title: "Creative Director, VISA",
      image: `${require("../assets/image.jpg")}`,
      quote:
        "It's all good. I was amazed at the quality of the Design. We've seen amazing results already."
    },
    {
      name: "Mark Jacobs",
      title: "Tech Lead, Google",
      image: `${require("../assets/image2.jpg")}`,
      quote:
        "The rebranding has really helped our business. Definitely worth the investment."
    },
    {
      name: "Lisa Bearings",
      title: "Brand Coordinator, Facebook",
      image: `${require("../assets/image3.jpg")}`,
      quote:
        "The service was excellent. Absolutely wonderful! A complete redesign did it for us."
    }
  ];
```

However this does not render the img but the alt tag.

I am able to import the img directly with the source, so the path is correct:

```
import img from '../assets/image.jpg'
```

Can anyone confirm what i'm doing incorrectly?
Obviously it's within the specific line:

```
image: `${require("../assets/image.jpg")}`,
```

Comment: the following answers solves your problem but if you still having problem then provide a codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the source in String literal. The following statement will return a string which is invalid.

```
`${require("../assets/image.jpg")}`
```

Either you need to pass the Image object by import it directly. Or either place the images in the `/public/assets` folder and pass the string there. Any of the following will work for you.

```
import img from '../assets/image.jpg';

<img src={img} alt="pic" />
```

OR

```
<img src="/assets/image.jpg" alt="pic" />
```

Comment: Hi Muhammed, I was actually following this video at 5:10: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1lx061sncM&ab_channel=WrongAkram. Are you able to explain why he does not have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution but you can just import those images in the same file as the Array above, like

```
import image1 from "../assets/image1";
```

then inside the array it could be

```
image:{image1}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the name you imported in your data instead of string literal

```
import Image1 from "../assets/image.jpg"
import Image2 from "../assets/image2.jpg"
import Image3 from "../assets/image3.jpg"

const testimonials = [
    {
      name: "Julia Cameron",
      title: "Creative Director, VISA",
      image: Image1,
      quote:
        "It's all good. I was amazed at the quality of the Design. We've seen amazing results already."
    },
    {
      name: "Mark Jacobs",
      title: "Tech Lead, Google",
      image: Image2,
      quote:
        "The rebranding has really helped our business. Definitely worth the investment."
    },
    {
      name: "Lisa Bearings",
      title: "Brand Coordinator, Facebook",
      image: Image3,
      quote:
        "The service was excellent. Absolutely wonderful! A complete redesign did it for us."
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks Junaid, why does it work at 5;10 in this video?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1lx061sncM&ab_channel=WrongAkram